# Fit video to the mobile device width irrespective if resolution

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I'm using the following but it is showing only half the video fit to the screen.

```
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container video {

  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: please provide jsfidler

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. This question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should consider using a [snippet](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @EmadFani, It's better to ask them to provide a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) in the question than something on an external site. Debugging questions require a [mcve] to be *in the question itself*. Having the code off-site is significantly less beneficial to other users in the future and has the possibility of completely invalidating the question if the other site goes away. Thus, keeping the code on Stack Overflow should be encouraged. That doesn't mean *also* having the code elsewhere isn't sometimes beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container video {

  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='video-container'>
         
  <video controls="controls"
           x-webkit-airplay="allow" 
           data-youtube-id="N9oxmRT2YWw" 
           src="your/video/path/here">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
<div id="video-local">
<video id="myvideo"></video>
</div>
```

For example Video, I used getusermedia (you can try different resolutions to check):

```
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } },
      function(stream) {
         var video = document.querySelector('video');
         video.srcObject = stream;
         video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
           video.play();
         };
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

and finally some css:

```
#video-local video {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100% ;
    max-width: auto;
    max-height: auto;
     padding: 1% 5% 10% 5%;
}
```

See also:
https://jsfiddle.net/v07rk7qz/1/

Comment: Didnt work. The height remains same as the original video. It is not getting resized.

Answer (score 0):

Adding **object-fit: initial;** did the trick

```
.video-container video {
      object-fit: initial;
      position: absolute; 
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;   
    }
```